# Curvature and Torsion explained

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $\alpha: I \to \Bbb R^3$ be a curve parameterized by arc length $s$, with curvature $k(s)\ne 0$, for all $s\in I$

$$\alpha(s) = \left(a\cos \frac sc, a \sin \frac sc, b\frac sc\right),\quad s\in \Bbb R$$

> Determine the curvature and torsion of $\alpha$

**Curvature** is calculated via $\|\alpha''(s)\|$, so then the curvature is:

$$\alpha' = \left(-\frac ac \sin \frac sc,\frac ac \cos \frac sc,\frac bc\right)$$
$$\alpha'' = \left(-\frac{a}{c^2} \cos \frac sc, -\frac{a}{c^2} \sin \frac sc ,0\right)$$

So curvature is: $\sqrt{\frac{a^2}{c^4}\cos^2\frac sc + \frac{a^2}{c^4}\sin^2 \frac sc}=\frac{|a|}{c^2}$

**Torsion**

To find this we need to calculate $b'$ which needs us to calculate $n(s)$

Finding the normal vector means to divide $\alpha''$ by the curavture?

I.e. $n(s)=\frac{a''(s)}{k(s)}= \left(- \cos \frac sc, - \sin \frac sc ,0\right)$

Binormal vector: $b(s)=\alpha'(s) \wedge n(s)= \begin{vmatrix}x&y&z\\-\frac ac \sin \frac sc& \frac ac \cos \frac sc& \frac bc\\ -\cos \frac sc& -\sin \frac sc&0\end{vmatrix}=\left(\frac bc \sin \frac sc, -\frac bc \cos \frac sc, \frac ac\right)$

$b'(s) = \tau(s)n(s)=\left(\frac{b}{c^2}\cos \frac sc, \frac b{c^2} \sin \frac sc ,0\right)$

So Torsion is $-\frac{b}{c^2}$?

Comment: Differential geometry is no place to forget your basic algebra skills and trig identities. Notice that $k = |a|/c^2$.

Comment: @TedShifrin $\sqrt{\frac{a^2}{c^4}}\sqrt{\sin^2+\cos^2}=\pm \frac{a}{c^2}$ gotcha. Well now I feel silly again

Comment: Curvature is the norm of the 2nd derivative w.r.t. the arclength parametrization. Just because they called the parameter here $s$ does not mean it is arclength. If it were arclength, then $\|\alpha'\| = 1$, but that is not the case here.

Comment: By the way, for all the years I taught differential geometry, I encouraged my students to try to factor as much out of such expressions as possible *before* finding lengths. Because $\|(\text{mess})v\| = |\text{mess}| \|v\|$ !!

Comment: Actually, @PaulSinclair, $c=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$, traditionally, here, so $s$ really *is* arclength :)

Comment: @TedShifrin Hopefully I have done that right, if you are still there :)

Comment: @TedShifrin - Its not wise to expect everyone to have the same traditions that you do! But in any case, all I was concerned about was a potential error, so I am happy it was not there after all.

Comment: Yup, it's right, @DifferentialGeometry. Of course, this is with doCarmo's sign convention on torsion, which is opposite most of ours. :) Well done.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I actually don't know what the concern means. Do these equations only hold in the case that $\|a'\|=1$?

Comment: Thanks so much @TedShifrin! It is indeed :), page 22 exercise 1

Comment: Yes. The Frenet equations require arclength parametrization. Otherwise you need chain rule corrections. If you want to see lots of examples, see my text (linked on my profile).

Comment: Thanks again @TedShifrin I will :)